# Pine: how to exit a trade partially if profit and to close it completly if loss

Tags: pine-script

Here is the code to exit a long trade partially (50%) after **10000** ticks profit were made:

```
strategy.entry("My Long Entry", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("My Exit 1", profit=10000, qty_percent = 50 ,from_entry = "My Long Entry")
```

But what if I also want this trade to close if **5000 ticks of loss** were reached?

I really don't see how to do this. Indeed, if I do:

```
strategy.exit("My Exit 1", profit=10000, loss=5000, qty_percent = 50 ,from_entry = "My Long Entry")
```

Then, if the trade first reaches the 5000 of loss, it will only close half, whereas I want it to close completly.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call two .exit() function with different ids. One for profit, one for loss:

```
strategy.exit("My Exit TP", profit=10000, qty_percent = 50 ,from_entry = "My Long Entry")
strategy.exit("My Exit SL", loss=5000 ,from_entry = "My Long Entry")
```